# Authentication with JSON Response Without Database

Tags: authentication, laravel-5.7

I'm at the beginning of a project. I'm using Laravel. I want to authenticate my users with depending on API JSON response. The JSON code that I get;

```
array:4 [▼
  "status" => "OK"
  "code" => 200
  "message" => "login Successful"
  "data" => array:17 [▼
    "user_id" => "133"
    "api_key" => "xxx"
  ]
]
```

As you see there is a line status=OK if response consists this variable my user login the system with using Auth. I can't create a new database for this system. Thank you very much.

Comment: it's better to use Laravel Passport